# How to mock read and write a single file after updating its contents using mock_open in Python

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest.mock

```
  def simple_read_write():
    with open("file", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    data["change"] = "some content"

    with open("file", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

How to mock this scenario, where the same file is opened in read mode and its contents read. Then after changing the content, the same file is opened up again in write mode to update the contents.

I have hit a road-block for mocking this scenario using `mock_open`.

The function I implemented for the testing the above code is below. It gives me assertion error and I am not able to properly mock the read write scenarios of the same file.

```
class Example(unittest.TestCase):
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data=json.dumps({"change":"old data"}))
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open)
def TestSimpleReadWrite(self, write_mock, read_mock):
    SampleFile.simple_read_write()

    read_mock.assert_called_with("file", "r")
    write_mock.assert_called_with("file", "w")
    write_mock().write.assert_called_with(json.dumps({"change": "some content"}))
```

Comment: Do you know how you can mock a different scenario?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated the word. It is Python. It was a typo mistake. I have mocked other scenarios of file copy, os.path.isfile, os.path.isdir, os.mkdir. shutil.copy2, shutil.copyfile.

Comment: @mkrieger1 tried using two mock_open (one for read, and another for write), but it gave me  `__enter__` error.

Comment: Please share the roadblock occurred with ```mock_open```

Comment: @Mithilesh_Kunal The roadblock is I am not able to use the mock_open correctly. I have provided the test code that I wrote after going through various examples, but it did not work. And if you are asking for errors, then I won't be able to provide you with that as I only get assertion errors. I know I am implementing the mock_open wrongly, but till now I am not able to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my above problem.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call

import check

class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("json.load")
    @patch("json.dump")
    def test_simple_rtead_write(self, jdump_mock, jload_mock):
        with patch("builtins.open") as open_mock:
            jload_mock.return_value = {"change": "previous content", "prev": "yes"}
            jdump_mock.side_effect = [True]
            ret = check.simple_read_write()
            self.assertEqual(ret["change"], "some content")
            assert call("file", "r") in open_mock.call_args_list and \
                    call("file", "w") in open_mock.call_args_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I just had to mock the `json.load` and `json.dump` and use `return_value` and `side_effect` respectively.
Previously, I was making the mistake of adding two `builtins.open` instead of one. Since the same `builtins.open` mock will contain the call to both `read` and `write`, I just needed to use `call` to check if `read` and `write` has been performed or not.